# create another table according to the descending summation of rows from the first table

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, sorting

Here i have an initial table which i have created using rcm.create() method.Then i have to create another in which rows will will be ordered according to the descending summation of the rows from first table.That means the row having higher sum will be placed first in second table.For creating the second table i have rcm.generateTab2() method .Which works as following;

1.call rcm.create() method to create the second table.

2.create the sum of each rows from first table and push it inside a rank array which contains an array of objects.

3.rank array is sorted according to descending value

now rank array contains object with three element.

## first td value from each row.

## sum of rows

## and the complete row which will be used to insert rows in tbody of second table

4.tbody element from second table is deleted.

5.then created a new one and attempted to insert sorted rows form table 1 to table 2.

but all i am getting is table 2 is pushed above table 1 in browser and no rows are inserted.

full code : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oun45ppo/)

[image]

main problem is inside rcm.generateTab2 method.So i am posting it here separately .

rcm.generateTab2 method:

```
    generateTab2:function(){
                var power=0;
                this.create(machine,process); //create the second table

                var tbody=document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                var trow=tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');

                for(i=0;i<trow.length;i++){  //get summation
                     var td=trow[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                     var sum=0;
                     
                     for(j=td.length-1;j>0;j--){
                       
                        if(td[j].innerHTML==''){
                            sum+=0*Math.pow(2,power);
                        }else{
                             sum+=parseInt(td[j].innerHTML)*Math.pow(2,power);

                        }

                         power++;
                     }
                     var first=parseInt(td[0].innerHTML);
                     rank.push({rowNo:first,sum:sum,row:trow[i]}); //pushed to rank array
                     
                     power=0;
                }
                rank.sort(function (a,b){ //rank array is sorted
                    if(a.sum>b.sum){
                         return -1;
                    }else if(a.sum<b.sum){
                         return 1;
                    }else{
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
                console.log(rank);
                
                var parent=document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1];
                parent.removeChild(parent.childNodes[1]);//delete existing tbody from second table
                
                
                var newTbody=document.createElement('tbody'); //create a new tbody
                parent.appendChild(newTbody); //append it to second table
                
                
             for(i=0;i<rank.length;i++){

                    newTbody.appendChild(rank[i].row);  //insert rows to tbody of second table
            }
                                
             
             
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've understood the ranking math correctly.

Please have a look at the demo below and here at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/73wn9Ln2/).

I've re-coded your js because I've thought that's easier. (But if you don't like using jQuery, I could have a look at your code and check if I can find the issue.)

I'm using these js libs:

- jQuery for DOM manipulation
- Underscore for array creation with `_.range` (could be also done with a for loop, so Underscore is not really needed)
- [Tinysort jQuery plugin](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) for sorting the table

For the sorting I've added the sorting rank (sum of the row) as data attribute to each row so `tinysort` can use this to order the table.

The CSS here at SO is a bit different then at jsFiddle (not centered text) in table header. Not sure why.

The default values (3 & 2) in the form inputs is just for easier debugging. Just remove the `value` attribute from the inputs later.

---

**Update 07.04.2015**

I've found the issue with your code. The problem was that you've stored the reference to `table1` inside your rank object. The `tr` elements in the object.
So you've overriden the `table1` because of that reference.

You can fix this with using `rank[i].row.cloneNode(true)` to clone the contents of the row. Then you can append it to your new table with-out the problem.

See the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/oun45ppo/1/).

```js
var ROC = {
    init: function (element) {
        this.$el = $(element);
        this.$table1wrap = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'table1wrapper');
        this.$table2wrap = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'table2wrapper');
        this.$el.append([this.$table1wrap, this.$table2wrap]);
    },
    create: function (machine, process) {
        var self = this,
            $tableHeading = $('<tr/>'),
            $table = $('<table/>').attr('id', 'mainTable');

        this.$table1wrap.html($table.append($('<thead/>').html($tableHeading)));

        this.processes = this.createCols(process);
        this.machines = this.createRows(machine);
        //var addRow = function() {
        //    this.$el.append($('tr').html(this.processes));
        //this.$el.append($('<tr/>').html($('<td/>').text('test')));
        $(this.machines).each(function (index, row) {
            //console.log(index, $(row));
            var $curRow = $(row);
            //console.log($tableHeading.length);
            $(self.processes).each(function (i, col) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    var letter = String.fromCharCode(97 + i).toUpperCase();
                    if (i == 0) $tableHeading.append($('<th/>').text('~'));
                    $tableHeading.append($('<th/>').text(letter));
                }
                //console.log(i, $(col));
                // self.$el.append(($(row).clone()).html($(col).clone()));
                if (i == 0) $curRow.append($('<td/>')
                    .text(index + 1)
                    .addClass('rowIndex'));
                $curRow.append($(col).attr('contentEditable', 'true'));
            });

            $table.append($curRow.clone());
        });
        //console.log(this.processes, this.machines);
    },
    createCols: function (cols) {
        var rCols = _.range(cols).map(function (num, index) {
            return $('<td/>').text(0);
        }); // [td, td, ...];
        return rCols;
    },
    createRows: function (rows) {
        var rRows = _.range(rows).map(function (num, index) {
            return $('<tr/>');
        }); // [tr, tr, ...];
        return rRows;
    },
    copy: function (sel) {
        //console.log($(sel));
        var $newTable = $(sel).clone().attr('id', 'copy');
        var $sortedBody = $($newTable)
            .find('tbody')
            .html(this.calcRank($newTable));
        //console.log($sortedBody, this.calcRank($newTable));

        //console.log('sorted', $sortedTable);
        $(this.$table2wrap).html($($newTable, 'tbody').append($sortedBody));
    },
    calcRank: function (newTable) {
        var sum, $col;
        newTable.find('tr').each(function (index, item) {
            //console.log(index, $(item).children());
            $col = $(item).children();
            sum = 0;
            if (index > 0) { // skip heading
                $col.each(function (i, cell) {
                    if (i > 0) sum += parseInt($(cell).text()); // skip first col 
                });
                $(item).attr('data-rank', sum);
            }
            //console.log(index, sum, $(item));
            //$(item).attr('data-rank', sum);
        });
        //console.log($(newTable));

        return tinysort($(newTable).find('tbody>tr'), {
            attr: 'data-rank',
            order: 'desc'
        });
    },
    reset: function () {
        this.$table1wrap.empty();
        this.$table2wrap.empty();
    }
};

ROC.init('#out');

$('#btnCreate').click(function () {
    var proc = $('#process').val(),
        machine = $('#machine').val();

    ROC.create(machine, proc);
});

$('#btnCreate2').click(function () {
    ROC.copy('#mainTable');
});

$('#btnRst').click(function () {
    ROC.reset();
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 1em;
}
input[type='number'] {
    background:lightblue;
    color:crimson;
    margin-left:20px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: initial !important;
    border-spacing: 10px !important;
}
th {
    background:black;
    color:white;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid white;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 7px black;
}
td {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 7px black;
    background:white;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
td.rowIndex {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinysort/2.1.1/tinysort.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Rank Order Clustering</h1>

<fieldset>
    <legend style='font-size:30px;background:lightblue;'>insert items</legend>
    <label for='process'>process :</label>
    <input type='number' id='process' placeholder='processes' value="3" />
    <br/>
    <label for='machine'>machines :</label>
    <input type='number' id='machine' placeholder='machines' value="2" />
    <br/>
    <input type='button' value='create table' id='btnCreate' />
    <input type='button' value=' reset' id='btnRst' />
    <input type='button' value='generate table2' id='btnCreate2' />
</fieldset>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: your code works, that's fine. but you didn't point out why one of tbody is vanishing and i also didn't ask for jquery :(

Comment: Sorry, for not answering your question with the first part of my answer but your code was hard to understand at first. But now I've found the issue, see update in my answer.

Comment: I don't know why,my code always gets messy.Anyway I also found the problem already.i was pushing each table row in an array and appended them in a new table.It caused all the 'tr' elements to shift from one table to another.Thats why one table's tbody element had ho 'tr' element.Then i found a solution for this also.I cloned each 'tr' element from the one table and append the cloned element to another.That's did the trick for me.Thanks for your kind help :)